# Linear convex set representation after affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, convex-analysis

$X = \{x \mid Ax<b\}$, $Y = \{y \mid y = Cx, \forall x \in X\}$. What is the linear inequality representation of $Y$?

An intuitive answer is that $Y = \{y \mid AC^{-1}y < b\}$, but $C$ may not be full rank.